# How to distinguish between system and user defined roles in a single database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, users, role

Is there a way to distinguish between a system role/user and a user defined role/user? As system role/user I understand a role/user which is installed/assigned implicitly at the time the database has been created. As user defined role/user I understand a role/user created "manually" afterwards.

The only way I have found is by looking at the result of

```
select * from sys.database_principals order by create_date, is_fixed_role desc
```

or by comparing the result with a freshly created database. Is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

The column 'is_fixed_role' on sys.database_principals is your answer, check [the MS document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> If 1, this row represents an entry for one of the fixed database
>   roles: db_owner, db_accessadmin, db_datareader, db_datawriter,
>   db_ddladmin, db_securityadmin, db_backupoperator, db_denydatareader,
>   db_denydatawriter.

Just use

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [type]='R' and [is_fixed_role]=1
```

Comment: These are the fixed **roles**. However the attribute `is_fixed_role` seems not to be exhaustive: what about the standard users like `dbo` or `guest`? What about `sys` or `public`? I want to detect them too.

Comment: Right. There's nothing that distinguishes those. You probably need to pre-identify them and add them in a where clause.